# Scanner array (n x n)

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

My code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Test1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int[][] num = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            System.out.print(num[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

the answer come out

```
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0
```

but i want to make

```
1 0 0
0 1 0 
0 0 1
```

Comment: u need to initialize ur array num

Answer (score 1):

As explain in the [doc of Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), a int is initialized with the value 0. So when you only declare your array without setting specific value, it only contains 0. That's why your output is

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

You need to first initialize your array to put the value 1 in the wanted places. In your case you want to make an identity matrix, so put 1 in the places that have the same index for row and column (In the diagonal). This should look like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    num[i][i] = 1;
```

Place this initialization before printing the array, so the full code will look like :

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scan.nextInt();
int[][] num = new int[n][n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    num[i][i] = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        System.out.print(num[i][j] + " ");
    System.out.println();

}
```